# Syntax Error from Imported Python Package

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use the [etl data reader](https://github.com/CaptainDario/ETL_data_reader) to read in the
[ETL Character Database](http://etlcdb.db.aist.go.jp) to be used for a neural network that recognizes Japanese Kanji Characters. I was initially using this on my system and I was able to load this package properly, but I don't have the sufficient recourses to work on this locally.

I moved to using Google Colab and when I try to run load the package:

```
from etldr.etl_data_reader import ETLDataReader #specifically this line here
from etldr.etl_character_groups import ETLCharacterGroups
from etldr.etl_data_names import ETLDataNames
```

I get this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/etldr/etl_data_reader.py", line 110
while(_bytes := f.read(data_info.struct_size)):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The syntax error seems to be coming from [here](https://github.com/CaptainDario/ETL_data_reader/blob/main/etldr/etl_data_reader.py)

Comment: See this.[New Features
Assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#new-features)

Answer (score 0):

Operator `:=` was [introduced](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) in python 3.8

Check your python version, I bet it's 3.6 or 3.7.
You should download 3.8 and configure virtual environment for that specific project.